# Interpolate array along first axis with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I'm struggling hard to perform a simple linear interpolation of a datacube of size `Nx*Ny*Nz` into a new one that would keep the other two dimensions constant i.e. the resulting output would be `Nxnew*Ny*Nz`. It seems that `RegularGridInterpolator` from `scipy` seems to be the way to go, although, it is not intuitive to me how to generate the input.

```py
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,4,11)
y = np.linspace(4,7,22)
z = np.linspace(7,9,33)
V = np.zeros((11,22,33))
for i in range(11):
    for j in range(22):
        for k in range(33):
            V[i,j,k] = 100*x[i] + 10*y[j] + z[k]
fn = RegularGridInterpolator((x,y,z), V)
pts = np.array([[[[2,6,8],[3,5,7]], [[2,6,8],[3,5,7]]]])
out = fn(pts)
print(out, out.shape)
```

In this mwe, I'd like to use new points `xnew = np.linspace(2,3,50)`, while keeping `y` and `z` the same, so the resulting array becomes of shape `(50,22,33)`. Also, how would one generalize this to an interpolation along 1 dimension for an n-dimensional array, while keeping the rest of the coordinates the same?

Comment: Not an answer, but just note you should avoid Python loops when using numpy. For example, you could have defined `V = 100*x[:,None,None] + 10*y[None,:,None] + z[None,None,:]`. That's the same exact thing but it uses broadcasting to do it all in one line and it is faster.

Comment: Re: replacing the loops - definitely good for users to understand broadcasting, but in this application, I'd suggest `np.meshgrid` with `indexing='ij'` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you can replace the triply-nested loop with a call to [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to make the code more readable and efficient.

```py
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')
V = 100*x + 10*y + z
```

As for generating the input to your `fn` object, note that its [`__call__` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.__call__) is expecting an input of shape `(..., ndim)`. In this case, `...` is your desired shape (50, 22, 33), and `ndim` is the number of coordinates (3 for `x`, `y`, and `z`). We can use `meshgrid` to generate the coordinates in three separate arrays, but to form the input to `fn`, we need to join them in such a way that the axis corresponding with coordinates comes last. There are several ways to do this, but the easiest is to use [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).

```py
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import numpy as np

x0 = np.linspace(1, 4, 11)
y0 = np.linspace(4, 7, 22)
z0 = np.linspace(7, 9, 33)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x0, y0, z0, indexing='ij')
V = 100*x + 10*y + z

fn = RegularGridInterpolator((x0, y0, z0), V)

xnew = np.linspace(2, 3, 50)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(xnew, y0, z0, indexing='ij')

xi = np.stack((x, y, z), axis=-1)
# or
# xi = np.moveaxis(np.asarray([x, y, z]), 0, -1)
# or
# xi = np.concatenate((x[..., np.newaxis, ], y[..., np.newaxis], z[..., np.newaxis]), axis=-1)

out = fn(xi)
print(out.shape)
# (50, 22, 33)
```

The meaning of "n" in your question about generalizing to "n-dimensional arrays" could be ambiguous. Presumably "n" represent the number of coordinates, that is, the dimensionality of your `V`. In that case, generalization to situations with any number of coordinates is trivial: jiust treat those coordinates (e.g. `t`, `u`, `v`, `w`) as we have treated `x`, `y`, and `z` in this example.

Comment: Thank you! After several hours, I've converged to your solution `xi = np.moveaxis(np.asarray([x, y, z]), 0, -1)` as you've presented. It took me a great deal to realize the format required as the docs give an example of evaluation at a single point xD.

Comment: Ah, sorry I couldn't answer sooner. Consider contributing the example to the SciPy documentation!